# my app token is useless, how could I access to the dataset

Tags: r, soql, socrata

I am trying to use my own generated app token to access the `socrata` data, but I don't know why my app token is useless, and it always returns `"forbidden 403"` and `"error in getResponse()"`

I checked the syntax for `read.socrata()` function, and modify the the parameters but it still not works

```
api_url2004 <- "https://openpaymentsdata.cms.gov/resource/gysc-m9qm.csv?$$app_token = <token>"
query <- soql() %>%
  soql_add_endpoint(api_url2004) %>%
  soql_limit(2000)
token <- "<token>"
data <- read.socrata(query, app_token = token)
```

I would expect that I could successfully logged in and access to the `dataset`, it now only displays `403 error`

Comment: Though I commiserate with your problem, if this is your real token then you need to change it ***immediately***. Don't bother editing or deleting the question, it is still plainly visible (albeit to fewer people). (And because of how the internet work, even getting a moderator to hard-delete it does not ensure anything. If it is real, then it is compromised and needs to be revoked.)

Answer (score 0):

It appears this data set is private. I attempted to access the normal data set, `https://openpaymentsdata.cms.gov/d/gysc-m9qm` and received a login screen. This indicates the data set is private, so you won't be able to access the API without logging-in an having privileges to the private data set.

As a note, the app token doesn't grant you access to private data sets. In RSocrata, this would require using the `email` and `password` options in `read.socrata()`.